# GUI version of the TeX Live manager for TL2015 does not work

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I updated to `Tex Live 2015` on `Ubuntu 14.04` and trying to use `tlmgr --gui` to update packages but it not working.

Installed the `perl-tk` through

```
sudo apt-get install perl-tk
```

and then used

```
tlmgr --gui
```

but it says

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and also tried

```
tlmgr gui
```

but with the same message

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any idea to solve the issue. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does it say anything else at all before doing a core dump? Any idea where it's dumping the core? (I would look in `~` and the cwd.)

Comment: @SeanAllred does most Linuxes today actually leave a core dump? I haven't seen one for ages. (I think is comes down to an env var as to whether a core file is left or not)

Comment: @daleif I know chrome did as recently as a year ago. You might be right about that env var -- I know I would've had mine set up to receive dumps.

Comment: Depending on what we find out, you might have better luck finding an answer on SuperUser -- I wouldn't go so far as to say it's off-topic on TeX.SX, but Perl's core dumps aren't our specialty, generally speaking :)

Comment: What do you mean with "updated"? As far as I know, there is no update, but only a new install. And after the installation of the new texlive 2015 you'd have to change .profile, log off and on again. See here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: The user *has* a working TL installation and cli tlmgr works. It is the gui that crashes which seems like a perl-tk bug to me. I don't see how a reinstall should help. On the other hand perhaps a forced tlmgr reinstall?

Comment: @daleif do we know that OP's tlmgr works with just cli? The whole thing is written in Perl, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Been debugging with the op all day. After a manual update of tlmgr the cli version at least now mention that there are no pending updates. I'd like to know from the op whether the Ubuntu is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: A very interesting test would be to download the installer from Tug.org, and run `. /install-tl -- gui` to see if that fails too. If not, re-install, if it does, then something is wrong with the installed perl-tk. Personally, I hardly ever use the gui.

Comment: @daleif: My Ubuntu is 32 bit.

Comment: That should be fine. Do you mind doing the installer test? To run it in gui mode it is either dash dash gui as an option, or just gui (I think both works)

Comment: I have the same problem with TL2019 on Ubuntu 18.04. No gui.

Comment: Hi @daleif I am having the same exact problem as the OP and I just tried your test. I ran `./install-tl --gui` and it worked. So something is wrong with tlmgr *in particular*!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is a definitive answer, as it may not be reproducible, but I had this exact same problem and accidentally resolved it. I tried removing and reinstalling `perl-tk`. That did nothing. I performed the test suggested in the question's comment thread: running `./install-tl --gui` worked fine, so the problem was indeed specific to `tlmgr --gui`.

After that, I gave up on the problem; however, I was having issues with texworks. I ran the following commands to resolve my texworks issues:

```
sudo apt remove texworks
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt remove tex-common
sudo apt install tex-common
sudo apt install texworks
```

`sudo apt remove tex-common` was because I was getting an error with `autoremove` after removing textworks, complaining about tex-common being missing from `usr/share/...` Note that I had previously done `sudo rm -rf /usr/share/texlive`,`sudo apt autoremove` in order to remove an old version of texlive that was interfering with my installation of "vanilla texlive" as per the [quick install instructions](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).

I believe the lines that fixed the problem are simply,

```
sudo apt remove tex-common
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install tex-common
```

After logging in and logging out, I can confirm that `tlmgr --gui` still works. I believe it has something to do with my reinstalling the `tex-common` package. Most likely, the old version was in the wrong place due to my previous apt install of texlive and the vanilla `tlmgr --gui` was somehow pointing to it so as to cause the segmentation fault. That is my best guess; but, in any case, the problem is resolved. If anyone else has this problem and manages to fix it reproducibly, I would be interested in further explanation.